# vscode service worker interface objects auto completion

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, service-worker

Why vscode dose not see service worker interface objects?
[lack of auto completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGHNn.png)
 While browser shows that they are still there
[presence of object logged in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wk0L.png)
How to fix this?

whole service worker code:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    console.log('V1 installing…');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('static-v1').then(cache => cache.add('/cat.png'))
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    console.log('V1 now ready to handle fetches!');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    const url = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (url.origin == location.origin && url.pathname == '/dog.png') {
        event.respondWith(caches.match('/cat.png'));
    }

    if (url.origin == location.origin) {
        console.log("Clients object: ", clients);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, did you find 'auto completion' for  'js service worker'?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use JSDOC syntax

```
/**@type {ServiceWorkerGlobalScope} sw */
const sw = self
```

and use the constant in your code.

```
sw.addEventListener('install', (ev) => {
  // the event argument will have ServiceWorker specific intellisense
  ev.wait
})
```

Excludes default libs such as 'dom' conflicting with 'webworker'

On the top of the file add

```
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
/// <reference lib="esnext" />
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
```

Comment: I had to use `const sw = /** @type {ServiceWorkerGlobalScope & typeof globalThis} */ (
  globalThis
);
`
in order for `// @ts-check` to work properly.